# Google CloudML Permissions from Dataflow - cannot recreate google tensorflow image example

Tags: image, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to follow this blog post from Google using their new CLOUDML tools.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow

Running from within their provided docker instance

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" \
  --entrypoint=/bin/bash \
  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
```

starting from:
`root@9e93221352d8:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/flowers#`

To the run the first preprocessing step:

### Assign appropriate values.

```
PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
JOB_ID="flowers_${USER}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
BUCKET="gs://${PROJECT}-ml"
GCS_PATH="${BUCKET}/${USER}/${JOB_ID}"
DICT_FILE=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dict.txt
```

### Preprocess the eval set.

```
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
  --cloud
```

returns

```
(27042c30421ec530): Workflow failed. Causes: (70e56dda0121e0fa): One or more access checks for temp location or staged files failed. Please refer to other error messages for details. For more information on security and permissions, please see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions.
```

Heading to the console, the logs read:

```
(531d956bf99b5f27): Staged package cloudml.latest.tar.gz at location 'gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/flowers__20170106_123249/preproc/staging/flowers-20170106-123312.1483705994.201001/cloudml.latest.tar.gz' is inaccessible.
```

I tried again authenticating with

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

and getting the key from the browser. Nothing seems wrong there.

I have successfully run the MNIST cloud learning tutorial, so there is no  authentication issues communicating with google compute engine.

I can confirm the path to my bucket is correct:

```
root@9e93221352d8:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/flowers# echo ${GCS_PATH}
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml//flowers__20170106_165608
```

but no folder flowers__20170106_165608 is ever created (due to permissions).

Does Dataflow need seperate credentials? I went to the console and made sure my account is open to the dataflow API. Anything beyond

```
root@9e93221352d8:~/google-cloud-ml/samples/flowers# gcloud config list
Your active configuration is: [default]

[component_manager]
disable_update_check = True
[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-a
[core]
account = ####<- scrubbed for SO, its correct.
project = api-project-773889352370
```

Edit: To show that the service accounts tab on the console. 
[image]

Edit: Accepted answer below. I'm accepting this answer because Jeremy Lewi is correct. The problem is not that dataflow does have permissions, but because the GCS object was never created. Going into the preprocess logger you can see

[image]

The tutorial google has shown is probably not well configured for the free tier, i'm guessing it distributes to too many instances and exceeds the CPU quota. If i cannot solve, I will open a correctly framed question.

Comment: Does the GCS object gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/flowers__20170106_123249/preproc/staging/flowers-20170106-123312.1483705994.201001/cloudml.latest.tar.gz  exist? If it exists check its permissions using  gsutil getacl gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/flowers__20170106_123249/preproc/staging/flowers-20170106-123312.1483705994.201001/cloudml.latest.tar.gz. Do the Dataflow service accounts <project-number>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com and <project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com have access?

Comment: No, it does not exist, the object should be created, presumably, from trainer/preprocess.py. My working hypothesis is that the prior step is supposed to write such a file, it can't because of permissions, and error is thrown when it looks for it.

Comment: Edited to show the service accounts tab from cloud console. Is something else needed?

Comment: Yes; it looks like the package should be downloaded from gs://cloud-ml/sdk/cloudml.latest.tar.gz and then uploaded to GCS when preprocess.py runs the Dataflow pipeline. The logs from preprocess.py should provide output indicating that the package is being uploaded and possible errors. You might need to add the line  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO) to preprocess.py right before the call to main to get more verbose logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the information about service accounts at the link provided by the error message.  I suspect the service account is not authorized correctly to view the staged file.

Comment: edited to add image of my service account tab. What additional config is needed for dataflow, in access to compute engine service account? The link suggest dataflow defaults to compute engine IAM. Something close to accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268735/using-google-cloud-dataflow-how-do-i-run-with-proper-credentials-on-a-gce-comput

Comment: If the problem is that the GCS package isn't being created then thIs probably is not an issue with the permissions for Dataflow service accounts. Creation of gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/flowers__20170106_123249/pr‌​eproc/staging/flower‌​s-20170106-123312.14‌​83705994.201001/clou‌​dml.latest.tar.gz should happen where ever preprocess.py runs and use the user's credentials not Dataflow service accounts. I suspect Dataflow's error message about permissions isn't pointing at the right cause in this case and the issue is that the GCS object doesn't exist.